# Kubuntu Network Manager setting wrong route when using OpenVPN

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

When I use the build in OpenVPN functionality of the KDE Network Manager in compairsion to the native openvpn program, I wont get any connection to the internet.

I have a Ubuntu OpenVPN server running. I just created a `conf.ovpn` configuration file and everything runs perfectly, if I set up the connection by `sudo openvpn conf.ovpn`. Which means, the tap device, ip routes and connections are established and working.

Now I want to setup the connection with my Kubuntu 14.04 KDE Network Manager.
I setup everything like in my configuration file and my manager says, that the connection is established. Also the tap device is configured, but actually no connection goes through.

I mentioned that the ip routes a set differently, so maybe this is the point for hands on?

No OpenVPN:

```
/sbin/ip -d route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.15  metric 9
```

With `sudo openvpn conf.ovpn` (I obfuscated the global addresses by `<someIP>`):

```
/sbin/ip -d route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
<someIP>/24 via 192.168.233.2 dev tap0 
<someIP>/26 via 192.168.233.2 dev tap0 
<someIP> via 192.168.233.2 dev tap0 
<someIP>/24 via 192.168.233.2 dev tap0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.15  metric 9 
192.168.116.0/24 via 192.168.233.2 dev tap0 
192.168.233.0/24 dev tap0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.233.49
```

With Kubuntu Network Manager:

```
/sbin/ip -d route
default via 192.168.233.2 dev tap0  proto static 
<someIP>/24 via 192.168.233.2 dev tap0  proto static 
<someIP>/26 via 192.168.233.2 dev tap0  proto static 
<someIP> via 192.168.233.2 dev tap0  proto static 
<someIP> via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
<someIP>/24 via 192.168.233.2 dev tap0  proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.15  metric 9 
192.168.116.0/24 via 192.168.233.2 dev tap0  proto static 
192.168.233.0/24 dev tap0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.233.49
```

Does the difference make the problem. And if so, how to set the routes correctly?

Kind regards!

Comment: I wish I had seen your question earlier. I posted the same question yesterday: https://askubuntu.com/questions/953402/kubuntu-network-manager-openvpn-not-routing-traffic-via-vpn-server. I think this is a bug with the network-manager-openvpn module. I'll raise a ticket and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

With the same symptoms, in my case happened that with the network manager it was being created a new default gateway as first routes entry, which in console command was not created.

I solved the issue checking "IPv4 Settings tab > Routes > Use this connection only for resources on its network" told [here](https://superuser.com/a/9604/586508).

Maybe it is not the solution for your issue (but I hope it would), but maybe it is for anyone around :)